# How to import the packages from https://google.github.io/dagger/api/2.12/dagger/android/package-summary.html into Android Studio Project?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, dagger

How to import the packages from https://google.github.io/dagger/api/2.12/dagger/android/package-summary.html into Android Studio Project? I was trying for a while but didnt get it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

// Add Dagger dependencies

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.x'
  annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.x'
}
```

If you're using classes in dagger.android you'll also want to include:

```
implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.x'
implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.x' // if you use the support libraries
annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.x'
```

Answer (score 0):

Add on your gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:2.13"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.13"
}
```

Comment: I already have those, but for example when I want to use AndroidInjectionModule I get "Unresolved Reference"